# How to set Hint text color for entire layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Is there any way by which we can set hint Text color (setHintTextColor) for an entire layout, i.e all the child elements in that layout?

Moreover, I would prefer to do it programmatically, and not through layout xml.

Answer (score 10):

You can create your own `theme` which styles the `colorHint`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_hint</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This works fine within the Layout where I use this style, but doesn't seem to work for the child elements

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395168/android-get-children-inside-a-view can help you?

Comment: Thanks for the link.. yes of cource i can find all the child elements and setHintTextColor in all of them, but I wanted to know if there is any way I can add the setHintTextColor property at one place(presumably at the parent layout) rather than going through the costly and messy iteration...