# Widgets of an Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way in `Android` by which we get something like Map and List or any other collection object that give us object of all the fields (like Text-view, Edit-text, Button and any other widgets) that has been used or initialized in an `Activity`?

Answer (score 3):

What you'd have to do is get a hold of your root view in your xml using `getViewById()`, and next recursively get its children using [`getChildCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) and [`getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) until you have them all.

Note that the `getChildCount` method only applies to [`ViewGroups`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (these are things like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`,...).

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395168/android-get-children-inside-a-view) for a possible duplate.

Comment: suggestion: get the root view by calling: `findViewById(android.R.id.content);` because it's the base Id of all activities. (I guess it's a FrameLayout, but not 100% sure)