# Inflated EditText View not selectable

Tags: android

The XML file(matrix_cell.xml) being inflated.

```
<EditText 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_edit_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_black"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The code inflating the view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.matrix_cell, tableRow, true);
```

The EditText View created is not selectable, the input focus remains on the previous input being focus when the EditText View is clicked.

Comment: what did you mean by selectable?

Comment: The Cursor does not show on the editText when clicked. It remains on the previous input that was on focus.

Comment: Did you try to select it manually while debugging the app? did you try to select it programmatically in the code? what does the rest of your code look like? (xml, java)

Comment: When you click, do you get the keyboard? if so, what happens when you type? does the number appear in the edittext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` to your `EditText`.

It can be done like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:inputType="text"
    ...
    ...
/>
```

It should fix your problem. More over, do you use any layout and make your `EditText` as its child? It is mandatory to do that. You have to remember that `EditText` is a view and not a `Layout`.

After the inflator inflates the view, use the `view.findViewById(R.id.edittext)` method to get your `EditText` for work.

**UPDATE**

As said by [Alexander Kulyakhtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721079/alexander-kulyakhtin) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395263/3073612),

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
>     View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
> }
> ```

You can get the child. And as said by me, use `nextChild.findViewById(R.id.edittext)` to get the `EditText` and work with it.

Comment: Thanks. Adding id to the EditText solved the problem. But I have used the EditText as cells of a TableLayout. Won't the id refer to all the editTexts in the layout then? Wouldn't I still have to use getChildAt() to get a specific editText?

Comment: You are using inflator! So it wont affect! Make sure table cells are a linear or relative layout and edittext is a child of them. Just call the id as like I said after inflating. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` in your `xml` as @Sibidharan said.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    ...
    ...
/>
```

In your activity, make sure you have initialized it.

```
EditText editText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)
```