# Inflated EditText programmatically but it's not selectable

Tags: android

I'm inflating an EditText programmatically, but it's not selectable. Why?

```
EditText child = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_edittext,
                mRelativeLayout,
                false
        );
        child.findViewById(R.id.custom_et);
        mRelativeLayout.addView(child);
```

The EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_et"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="Hey lol"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackFont"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="150"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

I've followed this answer

[Inflated EditText View not selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477455/inflated-edittext-view-not-selectable)

and added an id plus input type however it's still not selectable (cursor doesn't appear and keyboard doesn't appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the EditText into a layout, inflate that layout and find the EditText...

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="180dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_et"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="Text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>


</FrameLayout>
```