# Adding Layout dynamically for number of times on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

> The scenario is, When the user clicks the button, I need to add
>   particular layout in known position of parent layout for the number of times button clicked.

I don't know whether it works or not. I tried this following solution which I got from other posts

Button`onclicklistener`code is,

```
    parent = (ViewGroup) C.getParent();//c is a layout in which position i want to add view
    final int index = parent.indexOfChild(C);
    tobeadded=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.block_tobeadded_foremi,null);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button88)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addviewcount+=1;
            LinearLayout addinglayout=new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
            addinglayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            parent.removeViewAt(index);
            addinglayout.removeAllViews();
            for(int i=0;i<addviewcount;i++)
                   addinglayout.addView(tobeadded);
            parent.addView(addinglayout, index);
        }
    });
```

But I am getting  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.** In my code, before adding that layout, I have invoked the method  `removeViewAt()` for parent.

Can anyone help me to know what is wrong in that.And Is there any other way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly you want,Are you want to remove the previous layout and then replace new layout in place of that or you want to only add the layout on click of button?

Comment: I just want to add one more view to that layout(`addinglayout`) when the button is clicked

Comment: Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505356/i-want-to-add-dynamic-layout-with-text-view-and-edit-text-on-button-click-for-n/47506219#47506219), might fulfill your requirement.

Comment: In your for loop you are adding ' addviewcount ' times 'tobeadded'. that's why you are getting this error. first you must call removeview in your loop also

Comment: Calling removeView outside of for is useless. It throwing exception because consider i is '0' in for loop it will add view using "addinglayout.addView(tobeadded);" now when i will increment to '1' it will try to add view again, but what about view which is added at '0'(when i is '0').

Comment: @Joe add more code like which view you want to add, inside of which view new view are going to add(parent points to which type of layout like Relative or Linear etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an IllegalStateException because you've already attached the child to the root of the layout.

```
parent.removeViewAt(index);
addinglayout.removeAllViews();
for(int i=0;i<addviewcount;i++)
     addinglayout.addView(tobeadded);//Exception in this line
parent.addView(addinglayout, index);
```

Let's say addviewcount is 2.

Now in the first iteration, tobeadded is attached to addinglayout.

In the second iteration, you're again trying to attach tobeadded to addinglayout which results in an exception, since **The specified child already has a parent**. To solve this, **You must call removeView() on the child's parent first**.

All in all no child is supposed to have more than one parent. And the way you're implementing what you're trying to do is wrong. Create an array of View objects and attach them to the layout in a loop. This will solve your problem.

Here's a link where I've answered a similar question in detail few months back.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672959/2356570

Comment: Yeah,**Create an array of View objects and attach them to the layout in a loop** works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

On Click of button try this:

```
addinglayout.removeAllViews();
View text = new View(context);
textNotes.setLayoutParams(lparams);
addinglayout.addView(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SampleDynamiclay extends AppCompatActivity {

Button add, replace;
LinearLayout dynamiclay;
int newid = 100;
int replaceid;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sampledynamiclay);

    add = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.add);
    replace = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.replace);
    dynamiclay = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.dynamiclay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txt = new TextView(SampleDynamiclay.this);
            txt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newid = newid + 1;
            txt.setTag(newid + "");
            txt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            txt.setText("TextView  " + newid);
            dynamiclay.addView(txt);
        }
    });

    replace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newid = newid + 1;
            View removableView = dynamiclay.getChildAt(2);
            dynamiclay.removeView(removableView);
            TextView txt = new TextView(SampleDynamiclay.this);
            txt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            txt.setTag(newid + "");
            txt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            txt.setText("TextView is replaced " + newid);
            dynamiclay.addView(txt, 2);


        }
    });

}
```

}

[image: response screenshot in mobile of above code]