# How to check one view exists in another view area in Android

Tags: android

I have one relative layout whose coordinates are (0,207).

I have another view whose coordinates are (1138,750) and second view x-offset and y-offset (397,96) and I have calculated left (x-xoffset) and right (y-yoffset). Now, I want to check if the view a exists in view b area, then I want to get callback.

How can I achieve this? I am not able to find a solution.

- view A is imageview inside Relativelayout
- view B is text and imageview inside Relativelayout

I am dragging view B to view A.

Comment: use  of `getChildAt()` will return number of child in parent view. for more have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395263/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar there is anotherview is also there if we ll check that it will not work

Comment: @HemantParmar i am dragging view B to view A  and once i place that then we need to check viewB exist inside View A then we sending some call back

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: wait @VedPrakash i will share

Answer (score 0):

You can find your view inside another view by this code.It will help you find another view of the relative layout.

```
for (int i = 0; i < relativelayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

    if (relativelayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Imageview) {

       //Do your stuff

        ((ImageView) relativelayout.getChildAt(i)).disableAll();// Like this you can do something with it
    }

}
```