# set an attribute to large amount of TextViews

Tags: java, android

I would like to set an attribute to large amount of TextViews (above 30).

For instance - Initialize all of them and right after set attribute to insviaiable.

```
tv_something = findViewById(R.id.tv_something);
tv_something.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

And after a button press (`SetOnClickListner..`) change the attribute to visible

```
tv_something.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
```

What's the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Create a ListView of the Text items. And do onSetItemClickListerner.

Comment: If you know the parent ViewGroup of all the TextViews then you can loop over all its child Views, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395168/android-get-children-inside-a-view/11263152#11263152)

Comment: Offer more explanation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the use case for this but you can make [Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) it'll help you set common behavior for any number of views.