# android studio(java) finding view id with string

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator for just a practice, but I found that there are so many buttons.
I named their id like button+row+col
ex) row=5, col=4 -> id=button54

Since I have to attack listener to every button, I found it very annoying things to do this manually. Like,

```
findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
...
findViewById(R.id.button95).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Can I do this like

```
for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
        findViewById(R.id."button"+Integer.toString(i) + Integer.toString(j)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

or other way to make this easier.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with *a lot* of buttons I suggest you put them all into a ViewGroup (like LinearLayout, FrameLayout or something like that), then iterate through each View of that ViewGroup, check its instance then assign the click listener.

Here is some pseudo-code since I forgot how Java works

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.yourViewGroupName);
for each child in viewGroup.getChildren {
    if child is of type Button {
        child.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here some actual code to get children of a View: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395168/android-get-children-inside-a-view/11263152#11263152

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. 2 possibilities :

- create an Array with yours ID, to be able to use a for loop
- use [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) with `@BindViews` annotation

Comment: I have to declare all buttons first with both the array method and butterknife.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add an onClick "ID" in your xml and let Android Studio do the work.

```xml
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_54"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"

        android:onClick="oc_bt_54"
        />
```

and now in your xml file hover over the onClick, which should be underlined red and go to the red light bulb on the left.
Your Option: Creat Method in Activity xy.

and now in your Activity you will see:

```java
 public void oc_bt_54(View view) {

    }
```

No need for `findViewByID()`. Very easy and clean solution.

(Tip:
if you need the onClick method created in a special Activity, use:

```xml
tools:context=".your_special_Activity"
```

in the main layout of your xml.)